# How To Change A Cross In A Checkbox To A tick Instead for Foundation UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a UI where Multiple Check-boxes are there.I am just want to change  Cross in a Check-box to a  tick Instead?How to do this?I am using Foundation UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Foundation 4, remove the class custom from your form:

```
<form class="custom">

</form>
```

In foundation 4 by adding the custom class to a form, the checkboxes have the X instead of the checkmark you are looking for.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/custom-forms.html